# mysql select statement that returns all the days between both days inclusive where there were no negative values

Tags: mysql

How to Provide a mysql select statement that returns all the days between January 1st, 2011 and
June 30th, 2011, both days inclusive, where there were no negative scores

I am using this query

```
SELECT day_of_play, result
FROM table_pla
WHERE day_of_play BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-04-30'
```

and the result like this

```
day_of_play            result
-------------------  --------
2011-03-01 22:56:52         3
2011-03-01 22:56:52        -2
2011-03-03 22:56:52         4
2011-03-04 21:56:52         5
2011-03-05 22:56:52        -5
2011-04-30 21:56:52        -1
2011-04-30 20:56:52         2
```

**Notes. for others row that not date clause is allowed to be show negative values**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are expecting this

```
SELECT day_of_play, result
FROM table_pla
WHERE 
  (day_of_play BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-04-30' AND result > 0) or  
  (day_of_play NOT BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-04-30')
```

Comment: Thank you , it solve my problem, I also need the end of the date to not display negative values and I add "AND result > 0"  too :)